# Vagrant + VirtualBox VM aborted after sleep

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I have a problem with my Vagrant VM running on VirtualBox: every time I close the lid of my MacBook, the VM is aborted and I have to 'vagrant up' it again. I don't think it's the intended behaviour, and it's quite annoying to start over every time.

Checking the DiagnosticReports folder I can find a crash report from VirtualBox every time I close the lid with a running VM, this is an extract from the first part:

```
Process:               VBoxHeadless [6267]
Path:                  /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxHeadless
Identifier:            VBoxHeadless
Version:               ???
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        VBoxSVC [6215]
Responsible:           VirtualBox [6210]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-02-15 10:27:16.982 +0100
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.2 (14C109)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        453DE236-2C46-1B97-1C8F-D91BAF75710E

Sleep/Wake UUID:       21FE4DBC-7544-453E-B166-C48801F5CDDB

Time Awake Since Boot: 35000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       2700 seconds

Crashed Thread:        7  EMT

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000

VM Regions Near 0:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000100000000-0000000100008000 [   32K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxHeadless

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8bf734de mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8bf7264f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8b356b34 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8b355ffb __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8b355858 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   VBoxHeadless.dylib              0x0000000100080b91 TrustedMain + 44177
6   VBoxHeadless.dylib              0x0000000100080e5b TrustedMain + 44891
7   VBoxHeadless.dylib              0x0000000100079b31 TrustedMain + 15409
8   VBoxHeadless                    0x0000000100003d95 start + 7061
9   VBoxHeadless                    0x0000000100002234 start + 52
```

Is there anything I can do to fix this thing by myself, or do I have to open a bug report for the VirtualBox support team?

- OSX v10.10.2
- VirtualBox v4.3.22
- Vagrant v1.7.2

Comment: I started to see this yesterday after updating Virtualbox and Vagrant. It's frustrating. I'm considering reverting back to older versions of both.

Comment: tracking: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=64599

Comment: I'm having this problem again with VirtualBox 5.1.28-117968 and Vagrant 1.9.7. Host machine is Mac OS 10.12.6, and guest OS is Debian 9.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This bug has been report to [Oracle Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/13874).

And the bug has just been fixed and released in Virtualbox 4.3.24. You can download the latest version (VirtualBox-4.3.24-98716-OSX.dmg) from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads.

Comment: looks like there is a regression in 4.3.26

Comment: Can confirm, still happening in 5.2.28.

Comment: Same problem here with 6.0.14

Answer (score 7):

As chaserx pointed out, it's a matter of version. 
Reverting to VirtualBox v4.3.20 solved the problem, for the moment...

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is having this problem on Ubuntu, adding following lines to `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and restarting service with `sudo service network-manager restart` solved the problem for me:

```
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=interface-name:vboxnet0
```

Source: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/13873#comment:16

VirtualBox Manager 5.0.8

Network Manager 1.0.4-0ubuntu5